# Зависит ли сила сигнала от мощности сетевого адаптера?

Tags: wireless

Сетевой адаптер Аlfa awus 036nha имеет мощность 800 мВт, а Аlfa awus 036nh - 2000 мВт. Значит ли это, что если выжать оба адаптера на максимум, то alfa awus 036nh будет видеть больше точек доступа и сигнал будет более качественный нежели alfa awus 036nha?

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю, каким образом вы выжимаете адаптеры на максимум. Если вам нужно увеличить расстояние между клиентом и роутером, предлагаю на клиент поставить например такой усилитель https://aliexpress.ru/item/32808059225.html . Нужна еще любая направленная антенна, желательно параболическая (от триколор-тв подойдет). И будет ловить роутеры в радиусе 30-50км. Только держитесь подальше от антенны и от направления сигнала, если не хотите из фаберже получить омлет.